# Install Joomla On Windows 10 And Use MS SQL As Back-End

Tags: joomla-3.x, iis

I have Windows 10 and IIS up and running, I was wanting to know if there was a way to set-up Joomla with MS SQL on windows 10 and IIS?

Comment: This question may be a bit Too Broad.  This will surely consist of many steps and this site's Q & A format isn't really meant to be a place to park complete tutorials.  Have you attempted to do this procedure yourself?  If so and you got stuck or encountered an issue, please rephrase your question to be more narrow so that your question is more attractive and simpler to answer.

Answer (score 0):

As per https://downloads.joomla.org/technical-requirements, IIS and MS SQL are officially supported and there are some installation instructions at https://docs.joomla.org/Installing_on_Microsoft although these may be a little out of date.

For a more rewarding Joomla experience, a better solution might be to install [WAMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WampServer) or similar.